# Help with regular expression to scrape website

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression for the following (NB. ignore carriage returns, I've added them for readability):

```
<strong>Contact details</strong>
<p><label>Office:</label>&nbsp;+44 (0)12 3456 7890<br />
<label>Direct:</label>&nbsp;+44 (0)12 3456 7890<br />
<label>Mobile:</label>&nbsp;+44 (0)1234 567890<br />
<label>E-mail:</label>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:you@me.com">you@me.com</a><br />
```

I am using

```
/([\+\d\(\)\s]+)/
```

Which matches the number blocks and I can use and offset of 0-2 to identify them. The problem is it is returning white space as well which is screwing up my offsets.
How do I say "it must contain at least one digit in the match"?
I did also try

```
/\<label\>Office:\<\/label\>&nbsp;([\+\d\(\)\s]+)\<br \/\>/
```

But that would return

```
+44 (0)12 3456 7890<br />
<label>Direct:</label>&nbsp;+44 (0)12 3456 7890<br />
<label>Mobile:</label>&nbsp;+44 (0)1234 567890<br />
<label>E-mail:</label>&nbsp;<a href="mailto:you@me.com">you@me.com</a>
```

Comment: Scraping contact details - why would you want to do that... that smells like doing mass email harvesting...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good idea to parse HTML using regex, use a DOM bases parse instead.

Your regex does not work because its greedy, to make it non-greedy change

```
([\+\d\(\)\s]+)
```

to

```
([\+\d\(\)\s]+?)
```

Also `+`, `(` and `)` will be treated literally in a char class. So no need to escape them:

```
([+\d()\s]+?)
```

Comment: Thanks. I do use simple_html_dom to get this far but I need regexp for the final step of pulling out the number. Thanks for the tips.